# How to get AJAX response before sending to template using DATATABLES?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am implementing a log tables in my admin panel and I used the datatable plugin.
I created an ajax in my datatable but I don't know how to get the response before sending to the table.

I have this in my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javscript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#log-pageview')
            .on('xhr .dt', function(e, settings, json) {
                $('#status').html(json.status)
            })
            .dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "/secure/logs/visits.php?log_get=1"
        });

    });

</script>
```

In my HTML I have this:

```
<table id="log-pageview" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Log ID</th>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>IP Address</th>
            <th>Date Viewed</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Log ID</th>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>IP Address</th>
            <th>Date Viewed</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<div id="status"></div>
```

In my server side PHP I have this.

```
function get_pageview() {

    $host                   =   mysql_connect('localhost','avjunky_2','1qaz2wsx') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_set_charset('utf8', $host); //added for character encoding, made it global for functions /** added by rochelle **/
    $db                     =   mysql_select_db('avjunky_2',$host) or die(mysql_error());

    $log_array = array();
    $log_data = array();

    $get_all_logs = mysql_query("SELECT id, logged_id, ip_address, date_viewed FROM avjunky_pageview", $host);

    while($row_logs = mysql_fetch_array($get_all_logs)) {
        $log_data[] = array(
            'id'                    =>  $row_logs['id'],
            'logged_id'     =>  $row_logs['logged_id'],
            'ip_address'    =>  $row_logs['ip_address'],
            'date_viewed'   =>  $row_logs['date_viewed']
        );
    }

    $total_count = count($log_data);

    $log_array = array(
        'draw'                  =>  1,
        'recordsTotal'  =>  $total_count,
        'recordsFiltered' =>    $total_count,
        'data'                  =>  $log_data
    );

    echo json_encode($log_array);

}   

if(isset($_GET['log_get'])) {
    get_pageview();
}
```

In the server side I generated this kind of json:

```
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":2,"recordsFiltered":2,"data":[{"id":"3","logged_id":"7","ip_address":"122.2.55.11","date_viewed":"2015-03-16 10:10:42"},{"id":"2","logged_id":"8","ip_address":"122.2.55.11","date_viewed":"2015-03-17 00:05:40"}]}
```

---

```
{
    "draw":1,
    "recordsTotal":2,
    "recordsFiltered":2,
    "data":[
        {
            "id":"3",
            "logged_id":"7",
            "ip_address":"122.2.55.11",
            "date_viewed":"2015-03-16 10:10:42"
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "logged_id":"8",
            "ip_address":"122.2.55.11",
            "date_viewed":"2015-03-17 00:05:40"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know where did I go wrong. I checked the developer tool network tab and it seems that the ajax is not calling the URL.

In my AJAX I also tried to call the response from the URL like this.

http://mysite/admin/secure/logs/visits.php?log_get=1

But it doesn't load the data as well.

Comment: which version of datatables are you using ?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla, do I need to have a JSON file for this? Because I call this in my function in PHP

Comment: you can use PHP. But the point is the data should be of this structure http://jsbin.com/fokibe/2.json

Comment: I have an echo in my PHP but it doesn't display the data. Do I still need to use json_encode() for my array? or can I just return the array structure?

Comment: yep you should json_encode() and should be like the .json file URL above (I updated it again)

Comment: Ok, but my problem is the data wont pass in my table :( I used a callback but it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to use `xhr.dt` datatables > 1.10 should be used.

Secondly, the data should be of the following structure.

```
{
    "draw":1,
    "recordsTotal":2,
    "recordsFiltered":2,
    "data":[
        [
            "3",
            "7",
            "122.2.55.11",
            "2015-03-16 10:10:42"
        ],
        [
            "2",
            "8",
            "122.2.55.11",
            "2015-03-17 00:05:40"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/ebRXw/220/)

Comment: I already included that but I cant still get the data from the AJAX response. :(

Comment: I create a sample datatable without AJAX calling and I found out that the datatable.js and the .css doesn't load. But when I checked the page source it is there.

Comment: Ok I just created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rochellecanale/bad6wdgy/ and it looks fine but in my page in wont load. I checked the jquery version and it's the same. :(

Comment: Yes maybe I need to create a native pagination for my page. :(